# Fixed vs. flexible observation window in churn forecasting

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, churn

I want to build a binary classification model for predicting churn users(assume the user is a subscription).

In many articles like the next figure, I have seen that the observation window (customer event history) is fixed.

On the one hand, I can understand why they chose a fixed window -
the model compares users behaviors in the same period of time.

On the other hand, I find flaws in using a fixed window: users may behave in a different way in the churn window (also performance or response window). Maybe it will be better, that the observation window will not be the same for all the users and will end on the day that the user left?

What do you think is better?

[image: fixed observation window]

[The figure retrieved from Khodadadi et al, 2020](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9109662)

Comment: What industry are you applying churn for?  Is it a subscription services or something else?

Comment: subscriptions for a newspaper website

Comment: It could be a technical limitation: Most classification algorithms (Logistic Regression, SVMs,Tree based methods, basic DL models, etc...) can't handle variable length input vectors. So they would have to fix the length of the input window for practical reasons, even if what you're saying about customer behavior is probably correct.

Comment: In time series one often faces this problem of what window size of observations to use. One way to 'avoid' having to choose is to use multiple window sizes. In your example it could involve fitting different models to different window sizes and then either taking an average or maximum of the models' probabilities. The general time series keyword you can look at is 'multiscale modelling'.